# Click event for Status bar notification

Tags: android

I've a notification bar (2 events every days). A small list of array of string, a method to get a random number and the code below.

I need can click event and open a new activity with string variable show on that activity (not1[x]).

How will do?

random();

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher2;
        CharSequence tickerText = not1[x];
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Title";
        CharSequence contentText = not1[x];;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        final int HELLO_ID = 1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just Chagne your code

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,yourActivityclass);
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
```

and just use the code for String

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("key", stringValue);

Intent other = new Intent()
other.getStringExtra(key)
```

Comment: Cool! A question: "stringValue" in my code is an array: not1[x]. Is your code correct?

Comment: yes this code is correct  This is example how you can send something to the intent in intent there is method intent.purExtra("key",char[]) you can use this

Comment: thanks! In other class (Notify.class) I put: Intent other = new Intent(); other.getStringExtra(key); How define "key"? like a varible?

Comment: String text = other.getStringExtra("key");

Comment: When I click, no new activities runs, I've:  Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@412a7df8 attribute=null

Comment: Using key as a name and nothing

Comment: You can use this intent on Some click or any where Pls tell me exact condition what you want

Comment: Ok: notification bar showes, I click on it and will open an activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21157/discussion-between-pol-hallen-and-mohd-saleem)

Comment: i never find how to chat in chat room